# Ehcache key ... recovered from StoreAccessException: NullPointerException: null value

Tags: java, caching, nullpointerexception, ehcache

I am trying to use `EHCache` to cache (remote) image files my application use.

I initialized cache in the following way:

```
poolsBuilder = ResourcePoolsBuilder.newResourcePoolsBuilder()
         .heap(1024, MemoryUnit.MB)
         .disk(50, MemoryUnit.GB);

      configurationBuilder = CacheConfigurationBuilder
         .newCacheConfigurationBuilder(ImageFileKey.class, BufferedImage.class, poolsBuilder)
         .withValueSerializer(new BufferedImageSerializer())
      ;

      cacheManager = (PersistentCacheManager) CacheManagerBuilder.newCacheManagerBuilder()

         .with(new CacheManagerPersistenceConfiguration(TempDirectory))
         .withCache("BufferedImageCache", configurationBuilder)
         .build(true);

      cache = cacheManager
         .getCache("BufferedImageCache", ImageFileKey.class, BufferedImage.class);
```

`ImageFileKey` contains filename and additional image filter information I use.

Apparently cache is working, but in the following method

```
public BufferedImage getImage(ImageFileKey imageFileKey) {
      BufferedImage ans = cache.get(imageFileKey);
      if( ans == null ) {
         try {
            ans = loadImage(imageFileKey.getImageFile(), imageFileKey.getImageFilter());
            cache.put(imageFileKey, ans);
         } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
         }

      }
      return ans;
   }
```

when I run `BufferedImage ans = cache.get(imageFileKey)` and it returns `null`, I see error printout on console:

```
org.ehcache.core.spi.store.StoreAccessException: java.lang.NullPointerException: null value
    at org.ehcache.impl.internal.store.heap.OnHeapStore.resolveFault(OnHeapStore.java:810) ~[ehcache-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0 fa4b4a8afb003e55eb74a2da228cacbbd2038073]
    at org.ehcache.impl.internal.store.heap.OnHeapStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(OnHeapStore.java:733) ~[ehcache-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0 fa4b4a8afb003e55eb74a2da228cacbbd2038073]
    at org.ehcache.impl.internal.store.tiering.TieredStore.get(TieredStore.java:99) ~[ehcache-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0 fa4b4a8afb003e55eb74a2da228cacbbd2038073]
    at org.ehcache.core.Ehcache.get(Ehcache.java:169) ~[ehcache-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0 fa4b4a8afb003e55eb74a2da228cacbbd2038073]
    at com.cireca.overlaywidget.ehcache.BufferedImageCache.getImage(BufferedImageCache.java:99) [main/:na]
    at com.cireca.overlaywidget.ehcache.BufferedImageCache.getImage(BufferedImageCache.java:113) [main/:na]
    at com.cireca.overlaywidget.piccolo2d.PCachedImage.paint(PCachedImage.java:225) [main/:na]
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null value
    at org.ehcache.impl.internal.store.heap.holders.CopiedOnHeapValueHolder.<init>(CopiedOnHeapValueHolder.java:57) ~[ehcache-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0 fa4b4a8afb003e55eb74a2da228cacbbd2038073]
    at org.ehcache.impl.internal.store.heap.OnHeapStore.cloneValueHolder(OnHeapStore.java:1514) ~[ehcache-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0 fa4b4a8afb003e55eb74a2da228cacbbd2038073]
    at org.ehcache.impl.internal.store.heap.OnHeapStore.importValueFromLowerTier(OnHeapStore.java:1492) ~[ehcache-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0 fa4b4a8afb003e55eb74a2da228cacbbd2038073]
    at org.ehcache.impl.internal.store.heap.OnHeapStore.resolveFault(OnHeapStore.java:763) ~[ehcache-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0 fa4b4a8afb003e55eb74a2da228cacbbd2038073]
```

I wonder, if this by design behavior, or I forgot to provide something like copier?

**UPDATE**

Looks like this happens in the part of code, responsible to recover cache from internal components failers. Unfortunately, I neither can deduce, which components are failing, not disable these printouts.

For example, I can't replace `LoggingRobustResilienceStrategy` for just `RobustResilienceStrategy`.

**UPDATE 2**

The value itself is not `null`, I have checked. Null is appearing somewhere deeper. Also note, that message occurs when I am READING from cache. Also note it is not an exception, it is a printout in stdout. If I would put null as a value, I would get excplicit exception.

**UPDATE 3**

My later inverstigations (not finished) shows that the problem is probably related with copying between tiers. Also it causes some keys are never possible to write to cache (the cache appears not to contain them immediatedly after put). If I disable disk tier, the problem disappears.

Answer (score 1):

Based of `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null value`, looks like the value you're trying to put in the cache is `null`... ?
Could `loadImage(imageFileKey.getImageFile(), imageFileKey.getImageFilter());` return `null`?

Would this fix it?

`if (ans != null)
  cache.put(imageFileKey, ans);`

Or you really need to cache the absence of something? If that's the case I *think* you'll have to use a dedicated magic value (other than `null`) for that

Comment: The value is definitely not null. Null appears somewhere deeper.

Comment: If that's indeed the case, looks like you may have found a bug. You might want to put a small reproducable test case together that exposes the issue and share it on the ehcache3 github bug tracker...